# Save user profile fields through plugin

Tags: plugin-development, users, user-profile

I have added additional fields to my user profiles. I need to be able to change and save these via my plugin. How do I set those values before calling

```
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

Answer (score 4):

You use [setContentFromPost method](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#setContentFromPost-detail) on the UserModel if you are posting to your plugin, like so (this is what happens when you save your profile in the control panel):

```
$user->setContentFromPost('fields');
```

There is also a [setContent method](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#setContent-detail), which takes a [ContentModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/ContentModel) or an array:

```
$user->setContent([ 'fields' => ['field1' => 'value'] ])
```

Behind the scenes, that runs the [setAttributes method](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#setAttributes-detail).

Comment: That would have worked if the data were coming from the form post I suppose. But I am entering calculated data.

Comment: I added the setContent method. Haven't tested either, but seems like it should work. In general, you should check out the UserModel and the underlying BaseElementModel.

Answer (score 2):

Fred got me pointed down a path. Not sure why this works, perhaps someone can explain it to me. This is what I ended up doing.

```
$initialCredits = 100;
$user = craft()->users->getUserById(craft()->userSession->getUser()->id);
$user->getContent()->initialCredits = $initialCredits;  
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

Now, why getContent() worked and setContent() doesn't confuses me. I would think that since I am setting content and not getting it, I should use getContent(). Unless I am on the other side of the model somehow.

Comment: The User Model is 'getting' content for itself — all about your perspective I guess. ;) Glad you figured it out. This helped me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fred is definitely on the right path -- the setContent() call works just fine and makes a lot more sense then using getContent():

```
$initialCredits = 100;
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
$user->setContent(['initialCredits' => $initialCredits]);
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

P.S.  The way you're getting the current user is redundant.  Just use `craft()->userSession->getUser()` instead.